# How to make the toolbar go back to default?

Tags: 10.10, tools

At the moment,the main tool-bar is on the middle of the screen and there is no space on the tool-bar click-able  to get it back to the stretched position

thank you

Comment: What toolbar are you talking about?

Comment: attach the screenshot please

Answer (score 1):

To reset your gnome panels to "factory default" delete (or better move to have a backup) the settings folder

To delete enter a terminal an type `rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/panel`

If you log out and back in it should be ok again...

Answer (score 0):

If by the "main toolbar" you mean the top panel, try this: Alt-F2, then type gconf-editor in the textbox and execute that command (or run it from a terminal).

In the GConf editor navigate to /apps/panel/toplevels/top_panel_screen0 (where "/" indicates a level in the tree).

Under that you'll find a setting named "expand", and if you tick the checkbox next to it, the panel should be stretched to the whole width of the screen again.